# How testNG report is working internally when we implemented multi thread in class level?

Tags: java, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

I have a custom report where I didn't use any testNg api, and simply created by using Java API, and HTML, CSS, and JS files. It works as expected. But I had requirement to implement parallel execution in script.

It was implemented successfully but report mechanism is not properly working now. Because I enabled 5 threads, and 5 browser will launch and each will pick one tscript. Report is showing wrong outcome, like 1 script contains 2 script check points. But If I seen a testNG report everything is good. How it does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TestNG associates each [`ITestResult`](http://testng.org/javadocs/org/testng/ITestResult.html) with its execution thread using an [`InheritableThreadLocal<T>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/InheritableThreadLocal.html). This allows TestNG to keep track of state for multiple tests running in parallel. See [Reporter.java](https://github.com/cbeust/testng/blob/b1ac2e15f4a6698986746bf815bce67d0bb0a4dd/src/main/java/org/testng/Reporter.java).

Comment: Is there any sample code to achieve this task for custom report. However, many thanks for your inputs.

Comment: How TestNG report works internally and how to create a custom TestNG listener/reporter are two very different questions. If you want to create a custom TestNG listener/reporter then I recommend starting with http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#logging and then taking a look at the sources of *All Known Implementing Classes* of [org.testng.IReporter](http://testng.org/javadocs/org/testng/IReporter.html). Good luck!